# Python for loop always uses else statement

Tags: python, loops, beautifulsoup

I'm making a program that is going to detect a 404 page with a print. To detect these pages im using names from a array list to fill the url, like this --> steamcommunity.com/groups/(ARRAY FILLED).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json

names = json.loads(open('names.json').read())

def groupfinder():
    for name in names:
        url = requests.get('https://steamcommunity.com/groups/').text + name
        soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'lxml')
        clan = soup.find('span', class_='grouppage_header_abbrev')
        clantag = clan
        if clan != None:
            print(clantag.text,"is already taken")
        else:
            print('GROUP FOUND',name)

groupfinder()
```

The code in the for loop is supposed to run on every array name, but it just sticks to the else statement. It outputs that all the groups are found when they are on a domain.

The soup find is searching for the name of the group which all claimed urls have. I'm searching for a unclaimed one.

Comment: side note, to be more pythonic it should be `if clan is not None`

Comment: If only the `else` ever fires, it is because the `if`-test, whatever you might expect, is *always false*. In other words, `soup.find()` is returning `[]` in circumstances when you believe it should not. Add a line `print(clan)` after the `soup.find()` call so you can see what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is linked with the URL you are using. as it is right now:

```
url = requests.get('https://steamcommunity.com/groups/').text + name
```

You are sending a GET request to https://steamcommunity.com/groups/ (everytime) and appending the clan name (`name`) to the end of the HTML text.

you should replace that whole line with this one:

```
url = requests.get('https://steamcommunity.com/groups/' + name).text
```

Hope this helps